# What are binaries in hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I could not find any info on what a binary is in hyperledger-fabric.
This is used [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/install.html)
I already searched online but got nothing.
Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary is a pretty standard computer term. It refers to an executable file on a computer system. It's referred to as a binary because they are usually a file of bytes and not human readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have downloaded the samples, the binaries can be found in the bin directory, which will be up one level from the sample blockchain projects. There you will see all of the programs that are called when building and running a network.